# Glimpse Not working at all

Tags: glimpse

I installed [Glimpse for MVC5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Mvc5/) via `Install-Package Glimpse.MVC5`

I turned on Glimpse on the Glimpse config page: `/Glimpse.axd`

When try to now hit my site, nothing happens. If I turn off Glimpse the site works as expected.

There are no error message or anything http related in Chrome network tools, only a request of: `data:text/html,chromewebdata` with a response of `"Failed to load response data"`

This is what Glimpse put in my web.config when I installed it. Not sure how to troubleshoot this.

```xml
<httpModules>
  <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
</httpModules>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" />
</httpHandlers>

<modules>
  <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />

<handlers>
  <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just needed to set `dynamicCompressionBeforeCache` to `false` and it works:

```xml
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
```

Comment: Glad you got things sorted out.

Comment: where should i place this line in web.config

Comment: You should place that within <system.webServer>

Answer (score 13):

After adding the [Glimpse.AspNet NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.AspNet/), I found that the ASP.NET Development Server was crashing on every request because Glimpse was throwing a `NotSupportedException` *(I only found this after attaching a debuger to the dev server process)*. The exception's message said:

> Some environments conflict with current Glimpse async support. Please set Glimpse:DisableAsyncSupport = true in Web.config, or see https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/632 for more details.

After reading through the GitHub issue, I added this to the `appSettings` section of my `web.config` file to get everything working:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="Glimpse:DisableAsyncSupport" value="true" />
<appSettings>
```

*See: [Glimpse Issue: Allow users to disable use of Logical Call Context #632](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/632)*

Comment: This solved my problems with RDLC Reports, when I got a ReportProcessingException while creating a report. Now the report engine works again.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, instead of simply turning off compression, is to use the `@Html.GlimpseClient()` Razor Helper right before the `</body>` tag in your HTML.

The [troubleshooting section](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/wiki/Troubleshooting) of the Glimpse documentation covers how to do this.