# Why is this error with Glimpse, please?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, glimpse

I'd like to use Glimpse MVC4 and Glimpse EF6 in my ASP.NET MVC4 project but it doesn't work. I tried to look after it in the Internet but not much success.
The error message:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.Odbc'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see similar issues being reported on the [Glimpse Issue tracker](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/).

The issue [VC4+EF6+MySQL: "No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.Odbc'." #792](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/792) seems to match yours more or less and there was [a suggested solution](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/792#issuecomment-56390879) that seemed to work for the reporter.

Maybe you can try the same by adding the additional System.Data.Odbc provider to the EntityFramework configuration.

```xml
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.Odbc" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Comment: Thank you the answer but I have tried it with no success. But when I insert also this line into the web.config suddenly it started to work:<appSettings>
    <add key="Glimpse:DisableAsyncSupport" value="true" />
<appSettings> Url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715337/glimpse-not-working-at-all

Comment: Glimpse v2 removes the need for this all together and won't have this problem. So keep an eye out for it in the future.